# Документация по ant

Tags: ant, документация, java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где почитать документацию по ant? Желательно не перевод, а "выжимку", где описаны самые основные элементы и правила.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Ant](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant) кратенько описано, в конце статьи есть ссылки на более подробные руководства.
Так же посмотрите [Apache Maven](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven)